# MPI_Bcast in an if statement?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am experimenting with MPI and I kept getting this error when I was running it through mpirun on the command line.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure why though, because other mpi programs run perfectly fine.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int func(int num){
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (num == 0){
        num = 5;
        MPI_Bcast(&num, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    return num;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    printf("On processor %d, func returns %d\n", rank, func(rank));
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

the program is still giving me the same error. Is MPI_Bcast within an if statement just not valid? Does it still work if you try broadcasting when you're not the root?

Comment: I added the MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank) to the function and it still does not work.

Comment: You still don't initialize `rank`. You need to set `rank = 0;` before calling `MPI_Bcast` or replace `int rank;` by `int rank = 0;`. Right now you're passing some random undefined value, whatever was on the stack before in this place, it could be -42 or any other number.

Comment: Okay, this is now the fourth time I'm telling you. Initialize `rank` or it will not work. If you don't replace the first line of `func` by `int rank = 0;`, `rank` will not have any consistent value across your instances.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the changes above but I did in fact make the changes you described. Also that should not be causing the problem because I have other programs that do not initialize rank and they work as intended.

Comment: I've initialized every uninitialized variable in the code and it still does not run.

Comment: THIS IS VERY STRANGE.

After fiddling around with my code for a little, I thought "what if I just copy the code to another file". Sounds ridiculous right? BAM! Worked first try, and I was like "wtf?". Thank you S.Bandara for trying to help but it seems some other strange force was behind my code not working.

That being said, would anyone like to explain? Just for infos I am using Rocks Cluster Distribution.

Comment: Okay, good. Always initialize variables before using them. For an explanation, see the the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This code makes no sense. `MPI_Bcast` is a **collective communication call**, which means that, in order for the operation to complete successfully, all ranks in the supplied communicator (`MPI_COMM_WORLD` in your case) **must** call it. `MPI_Bcast` is also a *rooted* operation, which means that there is a designated information source and that's the process with the specified rank. So besides the requirement that all ranks must call `MPI_Bcast`, they all **must** also supply the same rank for *root*.

Your program calls `MPI_Bcast` only if the `num` argument to `func` is `0`, which only happens in rank `0`. In all other ranks `func` does not call `MPI_Bcast` and they simply finalise the library and exit. This results in `MPI_Bcast` eventually failing, as it tries to send messages to no longer available processes, eventually resulting in an error ("eventually" since the standard allows for early local completion and in certain cases, especially with small messages as in your case, the sends are buffered). By default MPI handles errors by aborting the job instead of returning an error code.

There is nothing that prevents you from calling any MPI collective function from within a conditional, but you have to take care and ensure that all ranks eventually make the collective call, no matter what code path they take in order to do so.

The correct version of your `func` would be:

```c
int func(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        num = 5;
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    return num;
}
```

With a "call from within a conditional" it could be:

```
int func(int num) {
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0) {
        num = 5;
        MPI_Bcast(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
        MPI_Bcast(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    return num;
}
```

(but that's plain unnecessary)

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `MPI_Bcast` as I see it in any reference document is `int MPI_Bcast(void* buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int root, MPI_Comm comm)`. However, you are passing only four arguments, and looks like you forgot either about the first or second argument.

What is `num` in your case, and what is your buffer? The answer to this will likely resolve your question, but I am also not sure why your code even compiles. If `num` is what you want to broadcast, try if `MPI_Bcast(& num, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` works for you.

There is another, **very serious** independent problem. You have some `int rank;` on your stack and pass this to `MPI_Bcast` before you ever initialize it. Who is sending? If root is, you could just as well pass `0`, or initialize properly by `int rank = 0;`.

Undetermined values for `rank` are almost certainly the reason for your job to abort because instances will be randomly sending or receiving.

Comment: You still don't initialize `rank`. At least replace `int rank;` by `int rank = 0;`. This will make it work fabulously, assuming that the rank corresponds to the root process.

Comment: It is still not working! D: I am including all of my code in next edit. Perhaps there is something beyond the function that I do not see. Also I should mention that if I include any printf statements anywhere in the code for debugging purposes, it will not output (even if it is the very first statement in the code!). This means that it is terminating somehow before the program even gets a chance to start. There are no errors when I compile the program with mpicc.