# MPI_Bcast hanging

Tags: c++, mpi

I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864075/using-mpi-bcast-for-mpi-communication/7867789#7867789) and added some code for testing, but some strange results emerged when I added new code. The results are as shown below. It hangs up here and was not able to go on.

```
[0]: Before Bcast, buf is 777
[1]: Before Bcast, buf is 32767
[0]: After Bcast, buf is 777
```

It is strange from two points of view:

1. It won't hang up when code is `if(rank==i) if(i==0)`
2. whey `buffer[1]` isn't 0 before bcast.

Here is the code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank;
    int buf;
    const int root=0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if(rank == root) {
       buf = 777;
    }

    printf("[%d]: Before Bcast, buf is %d\n", rank, buf);

    // newly added
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(rank==i)
        {
            if(i==1)
            MPI_Bcast(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    // end newly added

    /* everyone calls bcast, data is taken from root and ends up in everyone's buf */
    MPI_Bcast(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("[%d]: After Bcast, buf is %d\n", rank, buf);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

what I actually want to do is to realize the function:
each processor run some part of the processing, then after getting the results, broadcast it, other processors update their own result by combining the receiving result.

Here is the main part of the code (original code is from libsvm)

```
struct decision_function
{
    double *alpha;
    double rho;
};

int gate_no = 2;
int p = 0;

int nr_class = 8;

for(int i=0;i<nr_class;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<nr_class;j++)
    {
        if(((world_rank==i-2*gate_no*(i/(2*gate_no))) && (i%(2*gate_no) < gate_no))||((world_rank==2*gate_no*(i/(2*gate_no)+1)-i-1)&&(i%(2*gate_no) >= gate_no)))
        {
            // some process for generating f[p] here
            ....
            MPI_Bcast(f[p].alpha, count[i]+count[j], MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        }
        ++p;
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work, and I got some errors.

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Bcast: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Bcast(1478)......................: MPI_Bcast(buf=0xcc7b40, count=2340, MPI_DOUBLE, root=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Bcast_impl(1321).................: 
MPIR_Bcast_intra(1119)................: 
MPIR_Bcast_scatter_ring_allgather(962): 
MPIR_Bcast_binomial(154)..............: message sizes do not match across processes in the collective
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This block

```
    if(rank==i)
    {
        if(i==1)
        MPI_Bcast(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

means that only process 1 makes the call to `MPI_Bcast`.  Since it's a collective operation all the processes in the communicator should call it (at the same time).  In this case process 1 is waiting for all the others which, if I understand correctly, continue until they get to the next call to `MPI_Bcast` where they wait for process 1. And wait. And wait.

I'm not sure what you are really trying to do so can't really offer any constructive advice about how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I edited the question again. Hope it is clearer.

Comment: I read your comments carefully. Now I finally understand the problem. It's because all process need to call `MPI_Bcast`. [The question post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511833/mpi-bcast-in-an-if-statement?rq=1) also helps me a lot.

Comment: I have a similar error when running a commercial code. Is there a flag I can set to extend time needed to complete MPI_Bcast?